# EasyPHP Cannot Connect to Localhost

Tags: php, localhost, easyphp

I have had EasyPHP running on my system, but had to do a clean OS reinstall.  Just downloaded and installed EasyPHP again, and Apache is running. But when I try to access the administrative page (127.0.0.1/home) through my web browser I get a "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 127.0.0.1" error.

I checked Apache's httpd file and it says it is listening on 127.0.0.1:80, which is exactly how I am trying to access the admin page through the browser.  For some reason howver I am able to access the www folder with 127.0.0.1:8887.

I'm not very knowledgeable on EasyPHP so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue which was resolved by running the EasyPHP executable with admin privileges.

**Update:** I avoid installing EasyPHP into the `Program Files` folder and never had this issue again.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this problem by changing the listening port to 8887 like you did, but instead of saving it, do a 'Save As' and then overwrite it. It will ask you if you wish to overwrite the file, and just press 'yes'. This made the change permanent. Whenever I just saved it normally by pressing 'Save' instead of 'Save As', it would just create a new httpd file with the timestamp and not overwrite the original, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Dashboard and change the port from 80 to 8080 then reverse to 80

Answer (score 1):

Did you check apache error logs ?

In your easyphp toolbar you can see if apache is running (green icon)

By the way, try this command "netstat -b" and try to find "apache.exe" ( or "httpd.exe" depending of your easyphp version) listening on port 80.

But first, check your apache error logs, maybe there is a failure on your apache configuration files.

Comment: Checked the error log, nothing looked unusual.  EasyPHP does say that Apache is running (green light). I performed netstat -b and did not see Apache running, however, I ran TCPView and saw that apache.exe is listening, but on local port 8887.

I went into Apache httpd file and changed the listening port to 8887, but for some reason it resets back to 80 after I restart the Apache?

The only error that jumped out at me was this:
'[authz_core:error] [pid 3052:tid 1060] [client 127.0.0.1:49447] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Program Files (x86)/EasyPHP-12.1/home'

Comment: Just checked the conf_files folder in EasyPHP, and apparently each time I made the adjustment to the httpd file, it simply made a new httpd file followed by a timestamp, and kept the original httpd file at port 80.  

Going to attempt a reinstall to see if that will solve my problems.
EDIT: Same problem after reinstall.

Comment: On TCPView, did you see any application on port 80 ?
Maybe there is another app using this port

Comment: Nope, it doesn't appear that anything else is using that port.  I gave up and just decided to install XAMPP and use that instead, and that appears to be working.  I appreciate the help though.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same trouble today and when i tried to fix this changing the port by the EasyPHP program, this didn't resolve. If this occur try go to folder of the `program/apache/conf` and manually change `httpd.conf`.
Here the `httpd` of the program folder indicates `127.0.0.1:80` while `httpd` conf apache folder show `127.0.0.1:8887.`

I hope had helped yours.
Regards